# Странная задержка в несколько секунд

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

Использую `<input id="upload">` для загрузки изображения. При нажатии на `input` открывается стандартное окно браузера выбора файла. При срабатывании выбора файла (onchange) - включаю отображение 2х элементов, в них отображается canvas с загруженной картинкой. Не могу понять почему так долго происходит срабатывание оторажения элементов - 5-7 секунд.

```
$('#upload').on('change', function () {

    $('#upload-canvas').show();
    $('#upload-btn').show();

    var reader = new FileReader();
    var img = new Image();
    reader.onload = function ( e ) {
        img.onload = function () {
            var canvas = document.createElement( 'canvas' );
            var ctx = canvas.getContext( "2d" );
            var width = img.width;
            var height = img.height;
            var MAX_WIDTH = 1000;
            var MAX_HEIGHT = 1000;

            // Resize maintaining aspect ratio
            if ( width > height ) {
                if ( width > MAX_WIDTH ) {
                    height *= MAX_WIDTH / width;
                    width = MAX_WIDTH;
                }
            } else {
                if ( height > MAX_HEIGHT ) {
                    width *= MAX_HEIGHT / height;
                    height = MAX_HEIGHT;
                }
            }
            canvas.width = width;
            canvas.height = height;

            // Copy the image to the canvas and resize it.
            ctx.drawImage( img, 0, 0, width, height );

            // Toss the new down-scaled image over to Croppie
            $uploadCrop.croppie( 'bind', {
                    url: canvas.toDataURL( 'image/png' )
                } )
                .then(
                    function ( value ) {
                        $uploadCrop.croppie( 'setZoom', 0 );
                    },
                    function ( reason ) {
                        console.error( 'Image binding failed. Reason: ', reason );
                    }
                );
        }
        img.src = e.target.result;
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);

});
```

Если вставить в начале обработчика `alert('test');` - он срабатывает мгновенно, тоесть выбрал файл и мгновенно срабатывает функция, но .show() срабатывает только через несколько секунд. Пробовал включать отображение без jquery, простым js - тоже самое. Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема.

Comment: в размере картинки не может?